# Rails respond_with json issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, autocomplete

Right now I am trying to make a rails form.  That form has a text field that allows a user to find or create a venue.  On the backend, I would like to find or create by a venue name (which I know how to do) but I would also like to autocomplete that form field.  I received legacy code but am not too too familiar with it.  Right now, my controller responds wit json, here are the contents of the action I am using:

```
@results = Venue.where("lower(name) like?", params)
respond_with(@results)
```

Then when I go to run this, and trye in text into the field, here is what I am getting in my terminal:

```
Processing by TagsController#locations as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"td", "size_type"=>"in_one_place", "include_button_venue"=>"true"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Venue Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues" WHERE (lower(name) like'---
- term
- td
','---
- size_type
- in_one_place
','---
- include_button_venue
- ''true''
','---
- action
- locations
','---
- controller
- tags
')
PG::Error: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record
LINE 1: SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues"  WHERE (lower(name) like'---
                                               ^
: SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues"  WHERE (lower(name) like'---
- term
- td
','---
- size_type
- in_one_place
','---
- include_button_venue
- ''true''
','---
- action
- locations
','---
- controller
- tags
')
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::Error: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record
LINE 1: SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues"  WHERE (lower(name) like'---
                                               ^
: SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues"  WHERE (lower(name) like'---
- term
- td
','---
- size_type
- in_one_place
','---
- include_button_venue
- ''true''
','---
- action
- locations
','---
- controller
- tags
'):
```

This is good and bad.  I am not loading the venue, but must be doing something wrong.  Any ideas?  Specifically, I would like to search by the venue name.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are passing all the params into the search query.

If you want to search by the 'term' parameter (which is 'td' in your case') you could try this

```
Venue.where("lower(name) like ?", params[:term])
```

Comment: Will this be searching the name attribute for Venue?